# AWS Rds security group settings consideration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We've setup a RDS for MS SQL database. I'd like to limit database connection only from our own applications such as Website, API, others. Normally we setup the security group like:

[image]

The problem is it allows anybody to access. I'd like to only allow some IPs to connect. But I can't do that for my API app which it's running through a **Load balancer** because there is no fixed ip address.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are your "Website, API, others" all running in the same AWS account and region as RDS instance?

Comment: @Dusan Bajic Yes. In the same AWS account and same region. But probably in different VPC.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use IP restrictions. When configuring Security Group rules, in the Source field you can also enter Security Group ID of the Instance that you want to allow to access your RDS.

Example from [Adding Rules to a Security Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule):

[image]